# How can I expand call to variadic template base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I have a set of non-orthogonal policies, all of them implementing a common named method, the policies add safety checks.
I want users to be able to combine the policies to allow more complex validation without creating policies for each combination case by hand.
My approach is creating a new policy class to combine others.

The simplified example below shows C as the combining class, here the method id is combined. The expected result is, when calling id on C, to sequentially call the id of each base class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A 
{
    void id() { cout << "A ";}
};

struct B 
{
    void id() { cout << "B ";}
};

template<class A, class... As>
struct C : public A, public As... 
{
    void id()
    {
         A::id();
         As...::id(); // This line does not work, it is illustrative.
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<A, B> c;
    c.id();

    //expected: result A B 
}
```

The question is:  Is it possible to expand As... somehow to do this without using a recursive approach, just using the ... operator?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sure. You need a context that permits pack expansion - a simple one is a braced initializer list, which also has the benefit of guaranteeing left-to-right evaluation:

```
using expander = int[];
(void) expander { 0, ((void) As::id(), 0)... };
```

- `...` expands a pattern to its left; in this case the pattern is the expression `((void) As::id(), 0)`.
- The `,` in the expression is the comma operator, which evaluates the first operand, discards the result, then evaluates the second operand, and returns the result.
- The `(void)` cast on `As::id()` exists to guard against overloaded `operator,`, and can be omitted if you are sure that none of the `As::id()` calls will return something that overloads the comma operator.
- `0` on the right hand side of the comma operator is because `expander` is an array of `int`s, so the whole expression (which is used to initialize an element of the array) must evaluate to an `int`.
- The first `0` ensures that we don't attempt to create an illegal 0-sized array when `As` is an empty pack.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fb9bb3b59a8be30).

---

In C++17 (if we are lucky), the entire body of `C::id` can be replaced with [a binary fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold): `(A::id(), ... , (void) As::id());` [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a6YtC2IxRKE8O9Mt).

Comment: Wow, never heard about expanding like this before. It works great and pretty clean to implement with no explicit recursion. :)

Comment: This is a gem indeed, wish I can up-vote more than once.