# C++ template sort

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm looking for template code to sort template parameters, something like:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
list<T> sort(T first, Args ... rest)
```

All the types in Args are actually T, but I need to use variadic templates, so that I can small compile time lists like:

```
sort(varA, varB, varC, varD).
```

(In fact, I plan on having an "all_different", which would sort and remove duplicates, to asses if the 4 values varA, varB, varC, varD are all different).

Anywhere where this kind would have been already written?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use initializer_list here and, say, have a sorting routine like `sort({varA, varB, varC, varD})`?

Comment: You are not actually sorting template parameters (`T, Args...`), right? You want to actually sort `first, rest...`? @templatetypedef That will force a copy. This one doesn't have to if sprinkled correctly with forwarding references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward to implement, assuming that you want to sort the function arguments. Just build a vector (or a `std::list`, if for whatever reason you want to use it) out of the arguments, and sort it.

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args, typename T_d = std::decay_t<T>>
std::vector<T_d> sort(T&& first, Args&&... rest){
    // optionally static assert that all of decay_t<Args>... are the same as T_d

    // build the vector
    std::vector<T_d> ret;
    ret.reserve(1 + sizeof...(Args));
    ret.push_back(std::forward<T>(first));
    using expander = int[];
    (void) expander{0, (ret.push_back(std::forward<Args>(rest)), 0)...};

    // now sort it
    std::sort(ret.begin(), ret.end());
    return ret;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563282/2756719) for an explanation of how `expander` works.

You can abbreviate the "build the vector" part into:

```
std::vector<T_d> ret { std::forward<T>(first), std::forward<Args>(rest)... };
```

but this incurs an additional copy per element (and doesn't work for move-only types) since you can't move from a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to make the function accept only "Args&&..." and obtain T using a variadic type function? This would e.g. eliminate the "1 +" for "reserve" and the lone "push_back". Easy type function implementation: template<typename... Args> struct Head { static_assert(sizeof...(Args) != 0, "No types specified for 'Head'"); }; template<typename T, typename...> struct Head { using type = T; };

Comment: What, no `emplace`!  `push_back` could give you a needless copy.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk On a type mismatch? So be it (and it'd be a move). I don't want to allow explicit conversions.

Comment: @T.C. Good point.  Add a "explicit conversions will generate an error" `using no_explicit = std::tuple< decltype( R{std::declval<Ts>()} )... >;`?

Comment: @Yakk That can still be explicit, no? Just catches narrowing.

Comment: @T.C. Not in my tests: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3c47f2b292a5353 (replace `good` with `evil` and you get a conversion error, it won't call the `explicit` conversion).  Note I'm making a throw-away tuple type, not a tuple: the point of that line is `R{Ts}` construction, which should be non-explicit.

Comment: @Yakk It doesn't use explicit conversion operators of `Ts`, but still uses explicit constructors of `R`.

Comment: @T.C huh, yes, the difference between `R r{x};` and `R r={x};`.  So we need an expression that constructs with a `R&&` or `R const&` only, but we don't want to actually call it.  [How about this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c30eebab349d73fe)?  Could be done without my helper with a `std::array<R, sizeof...(ts) >` I think.

Comment: @Yakk Doesn't `std::tuple` have an "accept everything under the sun" constructor? `array` is better, but there's still the problem that implicit and explicit conversions can both be viable and yield different results, though that's pretty pathological.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing at a time:

```
template<class R>
R sort_the_range( R&& r ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::sort( begin(r), end(r) );
  return std::forward<R>(r);
}
```

some metaprogramming: (hana-style)

```
template<class T> struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class...> struct types{using type=types;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<class Default, class...Ts,
  class=typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<void,Default>::value>::type
>
constexpr tag<Default> type_from( tag<Default>, Ts... ) { return {}; }
template<class T0, class...Ts>
constexpr tag<T0> type_from( tag<void>, tag<T0>, Ts... ) { return {}; }

template<class Default, class...Ts>
using type_from_t = type_t< decltype( type_from( tag<Default>{}, tag<Ts>{}... ) ) >;
```

now, a function that makes a vector.  You can pass in a type for the vector, or have it deduce from the first argument, your choice:

```
// explicit T argument is optional:
template<class ExplicitType=void, class...Ts,
  // deduce return type:
  class R=type_from_t<ExplicitType, typename std::decay<Ts>::type...>
>
std::vector<R> make_vector( Ts&&... ts ) {
  // block explicit conversions:
  using test = decltype(std::array<R, sizeof...(Ts)>{{ std::declval<Ts>()... }});
  (void)tag<test>{}; // block warnings
  // make our vector, and size it right:
  std::vector<R> retval;
  retval.reserve( sizeof...(ts) );
  // populate the vector:
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{0,((
    retval.emplace_back(std::forward<Ts>(ts))
  ),void(),0)...};
  return retval;
}
```

and stitch:

```
template<class T=void, class...Ts>
auto make_sorted_vector(Ts&&...ts)
->decltype( make_vector<T>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) )
{
  return sort_the_range(
    make_vector<T>( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
  );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859ceda38f6fd2f7))

Comment: You still do one extra copy from the initializer list :)

Comment: @T.C. Point.  Wow, this code gets cleaner in C++14 and C++1z.  C++14 lets you package the work into an auto-lambda.  C++1z gives you fold expressions.

Answer (score -1):

This simple:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
list<T> sort(const T& first, Args... args)
{
    list<T> result{first, args...};
    result.sort();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this will incur extra copies.