# Function template works with local lambdas, but not with other functions

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

So I wrote a function that composes "sequentially" void lambdas so that I can use them at once in an algorithm:

```
template <typename F, typename... Fs>
auto lambdaList(F f, Fs... fs)
{
    return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); lambdaList(fs...)(args...); };
}

template <typename F>
auto lambdaList(F f)
{
    return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); };
}
```

It works if I use local lambdas, but not when I use functions in a different namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    void a() { std::cout << "a\n"; }
    void b() { std::cout << "b\n"; }
}

template <typename F, typename... Fs>
auto lambdaList(F f, Fs... fs)
{
    return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); lambdaList(fs...)(args...); };
}

template <typename F>
auto lambdaList(F f)
{
    return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); };
}

int main() {
    auto printStarBefore = [] (const std::string& str) { 
        std::cout << "* " + str; 
    };
    auto printStarAfter = [] (const std::string& str) { 
        std::cout << str + " *" << std::endl; 
    };    

    lambdaList(printStarBefore, printStarAfter)("hi");  // ok
    lambdaList(foo::a, foo::b)();                       // error
}
```

The error is `no matching function for call to 'lambdaList()'` with:

```
main.cpp:11:56: note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided
     return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); lambdaList(fs...)(args...); };
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Why does it sometimes work but sometimes not?

Comment: I editted your example to be completely self-contained. In the future, our guidelines for good questions are to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to invert your functions:

```
template <typename F>
auto lambdaList(F f)
{
    return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); };
}

template <typename F, typename... Fs>
auto lambdaList(F f, Fs... fs)
{
    return [=] (auto&... args) { f(args...); lambdaList(fs...)(args...); };
}
```

As-is, your base case won't be found by unqualified lookup in your recursive case - it can only be found by argument dependent lookup. If the arguments aren't in the same namespace as `lambdaList`, then it won't be found at all and the recursive step will always call itself. That's the source of your error.

The new ordering allows the base-case `lambdaList()` to be found by normal unqualified lookup - now it's visible at the point of definition of the recursive `lambdaList()`.

---

That said, we can do better. Write one function that invokes everything:

```
template <typename... Fs>
auto lambdaList(Fs... fs) { 
    using swallow = int [];
    return [=](auto const&... args) {
        (void)swallow{0,
            (void(fs(args...)), 0)...
        };
    };
}
```

And now we don't need to worry about any kind of lookup. If you have access to a modern-enough compiler that supports some C++1z features, the above can be greatly reduced with:

```
template <typename... Fs>
auto lambdaList(Fs... fs) { 
    return [=](auto const&... args) {
        (fs(args...), ...);
    };
}
```

That's downright understandable!

Comment: "As-is, your base case won't be found by lookup in your recursive case - it will always call itself." [Citation needed](http://ideone.com/aO86oA).

Comment: @n.m. Try the new example in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the namespaces... Could you please explain what does the (void)int[]{0,(void(fs(args...)),0)... do here? Is it a common pattern?

Comment: @lemko it is a hack around the difficulty of expanding pack expressions in a way that causes them to be executed left to right.  Here we create an array of ints (all 0) then discard it, and as a side effect expand a pack of expressions and run them in guaranteed order.

Comment: @Lemko Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30563282/2069064). It's probably the best possible explanation.