# How to unpack tuple with unknown size?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

Given,

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    std::tie(/*xxx*/)=t;
    auto &[/*yyy*/]=t;
}
int main()
{
    foo(forward_as_tuple(1,2,3));
    foo(forward_as_tuple(1,2,3,4,5));
}
```

I want `foo()` to unpack the tuple that's passed to itself.
Can decomposition declarations with `auto` or `std::tie()`, handle the unknown tuple sizes like xxx - yyy up there?
If yes, how?

I'm trying to think of another ways, maybe all elements could be pushed back to a vector of that type, once they're got.

```
std::vector<T> bar;
size_t baz=std::tuple_size<T>::value; //useless because it can't be used as:
for(int i=0; i<baz; i++)
    bar.push_back(std::get<i>(t)); //since i isn't constant
```

Using vectors was just a bad idea that failed.
How else can it be done?

What I'm trying to, shortly is; I want to get tuple elements in a for loop. That's why I think I need them to be extracted somehow.

Comment: Relevant question: [Convert std::tuple to std::array C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10604794/580083), [C++ Transform a std::tuple<A, A, A…> to a std::vector or std::deque](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42494715/580083).

Comment: what would that be good for? What do you want to do with the unpacked references?

Comment: First, why would you want to process a tuple of unknown size and unknown types? If the arguments list is homogeneous, then it's probably not a use case for a tuple.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'm trying to find a way and then understand it. The argument list isn't homogeneous.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I plan to use some of them in recursive function calls, and other arguments will show which ones and how.

Comment: @Xemdocia: [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfd015499abeb36c) for your deleted question.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, but how can I map these all into one single name of "foo" and let it be chosen among overloads? Also why it gives a set of errors when I change it from `std::map` to `std::multimap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to unpack tuple with unknown size?
>
> ```
> auto &[/*yyy*/]=t;
> ```

You can't.

> maybe all elements could be pushed back to a vector of that type

Use `std::apply`:

```
std::vector<int> baz;
std::apply([&baz](auto... args) {
    (baz.push_back(args), ...);
}, t);
```

Comment: Can you show me a small example on how it's done? I tried to use your solution but can't compile. It says `expansion pattern 'int' contains no argument packs`

Comment: `int...` doesn't work here. It has to be `auto...`, or `std::same_as<int> auto...` if you want to show off. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good catch. I didn't verify correctness.

Comment: I couldn't compile it also with `auto...`. Can you please verify it and show how it will compile well?

Comment: @Xemdocia When program does not compile, first step is to read the error message.

Comment: @eerorika Now, it compiles well after your edit. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm trying to, shortly is; I want to get tuple elements in a for loop.

You don't need to unpack a tuple to iterate over it. Here's how I'd do it:

```
template <typename Integer, Integer ...I, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for_each(std::integer_sequence<Integer, I...>, F &&func)
{
    (func(std::integral_constant<Integer, I>{}) , ...);
}

template <auto N, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for(F &&func)
{
    if constexpr (N > 0)
    {
        constexpr_for_each(std::make_integer_sequence<decltype(N), N>{}, std::forward<F>(func));
    }
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    constexpr_for<std::tuple_size_v<T>>([&](auto index)
    {
        constexpr auto i = index.value;

        std::cout << std::get<i>(t) << '\n';
    });
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I can't understand the logic behind it. I haven't learned about _constant expressions_ yet. I'll check it about it, thanks.