# Variadic function that accepts arguments of same type at compile time and iterate on them

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-functions, function-templates

I am looking for a way to implement Variadic function that accepts arguments of **same type** at **compile-time** and should be able to ***iterate on them***. The variadic parameters are at the end with all of them having the same type.
Something like below -

```
void SampleFunc(Other arguments(String may be)..., int... arg)
{
   for (const auto& val : arg)
   {
      // Each argument available here.
   }
}
```

then I will call this function like below -

```
SampleFunc("String", "{1,2,3,4})
```

**Most important thing is that variadic parameters are hardcoded every time the function is called so I should be able to generate this Variadic argument at compile time.**

Right now I am accepting function parameters as shown below -

```
void SampleFunc(std::string str, std::vector<int>& nums)
```

But this adds run time cost of constructing a vector every time function is called which I want to avoid.

---

**UPDATE :-**

I forgot to mention that this function has other parameters at the start. It is my bad, sorry about that. I have updated my example now.

Comment: To your update: you still can use the answer given below, just need to change the function signature: `template <typename... Args> 
void SampleFunc(const atd::string& str, /* other arguments */ , Args&&... args)`

Answer (score 2):

If the arguments are known at compile-time, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) you can do something like

```
#include <utility> // std::forward

template <typename Type>
void doSomething(Type&& arg) /* noexcept */
{
   // Each argument available here.
   std::cout << arg << "\n";
}

template <typename... Args> 
void SampleFunc(Args&&... args) /* noexcept */
{
   (doSomething(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

Now you could call the function like

```
SampleFunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

and using `doSomething` you can do something with each arguments.

**([See a Demo Online](https://godbolt.org/z/oKWGv9))**

---

In previous compilers, you could imitate [the fold expression via expander trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563254/how-can-i-expand-call-to-variadic-template-base-classes/30563282#30563282), as follows

```
template <typename Type>
void doSomething(Type&& arg) /* noexcept */
{
   // Each argument available here.
   std::cout << arg << "\n";
}

template <typename... Args> 
void SampleFunc(Args&&... args) /* noexcept */
{
   using dummy = int[];
   (void)dummy {
      0, (doSomething(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
   };
}
```

**([See a Demo Online](https://godbolt.org/z/KWeoca))**

Answer (score 1):

Iterate on variadic arguments is the simplest part: you tagged C++17 so you can use template folding, as suggested by JeJo, or other ways (recursion, initialization of an unused array).

More complicated is impose that all the arguments are exactly of the same type.

Obviously you can use SFINAE to impose that the deduced type are of the same type, but if you pass arguments of the different types, by example

```
foo(1l, 2l, 3l, 4); // long, long, long, int
```

when an argument is convertible to the type of the others, the code doesn't compile.

If you accept to pass through an additional function and that your function is a method of a template struct, you can start with an `using` that select the type from a couple type/index

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using get_type = T;
```

you can write the template struct as follows

```
template <typename...>
struct bar;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   void operator() (std::string const & str, get_type<T, Is> const & ... ts)
    { ((std::cout << ts << ' '), ..., (std::cout << '\n')); }
 };
```

Observe that the arguments following `str` in the `operator()` are all of type `T`, where `T` is the first template argument of the struct.

The additional function is

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::string const & str, Ts const & ... ts)
 { bar<T, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>>{}(str, ts...); }
```

You can call `foo()` as follows

```
foo<int>("string", 1, 2, 3, 4l);
```

Observe that a `long` value (`4l`) is accepted because is converted to `int`.

You can also directly call the `bar::operator()`, if you prefer

```
bar<int, std::make_index_sequence<4u>>{}("string", 10, 20, 30, 40);
```

but you have to explicit the second template argument so there is some redundancies.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using get_type = T;

template <typename...>
struct bar;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   void operator() (std::string const & str, get_type<T, Is> const & ... ts)
    { ((std::cout << ts << ' '), ..., (std::cout << '\n')); }
 };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::string const & str, Ts const & ... ts)
 { bar<T, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>>{}(str, ts...); }

int main ()
 {
   foo<int>("string", 1, 2, 3, 4l); // a long value is converted to int

   bar<int, std::make_index_sequence<4u>>{}("string", 10, 20, 30, 40);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The variadic parameters are at the end with all of them having the same type.

Whereas `std::vector` might have the overhead of extra allocation, you might simply use `std::initializer_list` instead (of variadic).

```
void SampleFunc(std::string str, std::initializer_list<int>& nums)
{
    for (int val : nums)
    {
        // Each argument available here.
    }
}
```

With call similar to

```
SampleFunc("String", {1, 2, 3, 4});
```