# Why I need default sum function, for a variadic template sum?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, function-templates

I want to calculate the sum of any number of arguments given to function `sum`. Assuming that integers given to the function will satisfy `operator+`.

If I comment out the function `sum()` (the one having no arguments), the code does not compile. And if I uncomment it, the code does compile and run, but never hits the function `sum()`.

I can't seem to understand that why do we need to have `sum()` function at all as I am using condition on `sizeof...(Args)`

Will really appreciate it if someone can help me understand this?

```
/*
int sum() 
{
    std::cout << "Sum with 0 Args" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
*/

template <typename T, typename...Args>
T sum(T first, Args...args) 
{
    // std::cout << sizeof...(Args) << std::endl;
    if (sizeof...(Args) != 0) 
    {
        return first + sum(args...);
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Found 0 args" << std::endl;
        return first;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum(1.2, 3.5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Once I uncomment function sum(), I get below output -

```
Found 0 args
6
Found 0 args
4.7
```

Basically `sum()` never get called which is expected, but then why do we need it in the first place?

Comment: Do you know what `if constexpr` is, why it's needed, how it works, and how to use it? In C++, even if something "never get called", it still must be valid C++. Unless there's `if constexpr` involved.

Comment: Why do you pick two C++ versions? Do you use them both in a single code?

Answer (score 5):

> Basically `sum()` never get called which is expected but then why do we need it in the first place?

When you use the normal `if` statement, like in your code, the both branches are checked, and both must be compilable. When the `sum` is called recursively, the last function call is with no arguments. For this case to be true, the compiler requires a `sum` function with no arguments.

On the other hand, since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), we have [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if), by which we can retain only the true branches at compile time. That means, just changing the code as follows, you no longer required the `sum()` with no argument anymore.

Read more here: ***[Difference between `if constexpr` and `if`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if)***

```
template <typename T, typename...Args>
T sum(T first, Args...args) 
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) != 0) 
    // ^^^^^^^^^^
    {
       // .... as before
    }
    else {
       // .... as before
    }
}
```

---

However, in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), you may achieve a single `sum` function, by slightly tricky/ hacky **<sup>†</sup>** *[fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)*:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::common_type

template <typename...Args>
auto sum(Args...args) -> typename std::common_type<Args...>::type
{
    using unused = int[];
    typename std::common_type<Args...>::type  total{};
    return static_cast<void>(unused{ 0, (total += args, 0)...}), total;
}
```

***[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xxs8vE1Tn)***

---

**<sup>†</sup>** References:

- [How can I expand call to variadic template base classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563254/how-can-i-expand-call-to-variadic-template-base-classes/30563282#30563282)
- [Variadic template pack expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion)

Answer (score 0):

From C++17 you can use a fold expression for you recursive bit, and you have to use if constexpr for compile time if.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... args_t>
auto sum(args_t&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (args + ...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum() << "\n";
    std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP picked C++14 that doesn't have if constexpr.

Comment: You can also `return (0 + ... + args);`, so you don't need the special case for zero arguments :-) I think the anwer is still valid even though it's C++17 for anyone having the same problem who might not be restricted to C++14.

Comment: @chrysante There is a bunch of such questions with answers for C++17, thus one more such C++17 answer is not needed when C++14 has been asked.

Comment: @chrysante thanks for that little tip... somehow I always limited my fold expressions two to parts ;)

Answer (score 0):

I missed the C++11 requirement earlier. Here is an example that should be C++ compatible. Demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/js_WXEeiC

```
#include <iostream>

namespace details
{
    template<typename arg1_t>
    inline constexpr bool same_type()
    {
        return true;
    }

    template<typename arg1_t, typename arg2_t, typename... args_t>
    inline constexpr bool same_type()
    {
        return std::is_same<arg1_t, arg2_t>::value && same_type<arg2_t, args_t...>();
    }

    template<typename arg_t>
    arg_t sum(arg_t value)
    {
        return value;
    }


    template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
    arg_t sum(arg_t value, args_t... values)
    {
        return value + sum(std::forward<args_t>(values)...);
    }
}

template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
auto sum(arg_t value, args_t... values)
-> typename std::enable_if<details::same_type<arg_t, args_t...>(), arg_t>::type
{
    return details::sum(value, values...);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(details::same_type<int>());
    static_assert(details::same_type<int, int>());
    static_assert(details::same_type<int, int, int>());
    static_assert(!details::same_type<int, int, double>());


    std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```